# Makefile double ampersand (&&) giving an error

Tags: makefile

This is giving me an error that even though it is ignored due to the .IGNORE directive it is annoying. The error shows when **$(basename $<).err** does not exists. The line in the recipe looks like this:

```
[ -r "$(basename $<).err" ] && mv -f $(basename $<).err anotherName.err
```

I think the square bracket test returns **false** and this is interpreted by make as an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  The test fails which causes the expression to exit with a non-0 (false) exit code, which make interprets to be an error.

You can either invert the test:

```
[ ! -r "$(basename $<).err" ] || mv -f $(basename $<).err anotherName.err
```

or add an "else true":

```
[ -r "$(basename $<).err" ] && mv -f $(basename $<).err anotherName.err || true
```

Comment: Great !!. That worked. I used the **|| true** at the end in order to maintained its readability.

Comment: By the way, before that I tried to put the whole command inside a shell like this **$(shell ... )** and the result was that the **mv -f** does not happens when the file does exists. That is weird, I do not have an explanation for that.

Comment: I would need to see the actual change you made.  But in general it's always a bad idea to use `$(shell ...)` inside a recipe.  It's already confusing enough that there are some things evaluated by make and some by the shell... adding in a new layer that is evaluated by make and the shell before the rest is evaluated by the shell is just madness.